# Execution timed out (12000 ms): Is there a better way to do this problem?

Tags: c++

I've had a long break from coding, so I've been doing some coding problems.
In this one, I've passed the tests but the issue lies in my inefficient code. Here's the task:

> Given a vector 'arr' and a number n, create a new vector that contains each number of arr at most n times without reordering. For example if n = 2, and the input is [1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3], you take [1,2,3,1,2], drop the next [1,2] since this would lead to 1 and 2 being in the result 3 times, and then take 3, which leads to [1,2,3,1,2,3].

```
e.g.
  
deleteNth ([1,1,1,1],2) // return [1,1]

deleteNth ([20,37,20,21],1) // return [20,37,21]
```

and here's my code:

```
std::vector<int> deleteNth(std::vector<int> arr, int n)
{
  std::vector<int>::iterator it=(arr.begin());
  for(;it!=arr.end();it++){
    int temp=*it;
    int counter=0;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it2=it;
    
    for(;it!=arr.end();it++){
      if(*it==temp){
        counter++;
    
        if(counter>n){
          arr.erase(it);
        }
      }
      it=it2;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Sorry for the cringe caused, and any help will be most appreciated!

Comment: For a general optimization you might want to learn about references. For a better algorithm you need [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or maybe [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)

Comment: I would propose using a `std::unorderedmap<int, int>`.I would create a new `std::vector<int> result` to store the result. You add the elements into the unordered map`for(std::size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(): ++i) { myUnorderedMap[arr[i]] = std::max(n, myUnorderedMap[arr[i]] + 1)}`. Then you go with a for loop through the `arr`, check if the element `arr[i]` in the map has the `count` bigger than 0, add it to your `result` array and decrease the `count` for that element in the map.Try to count how many times you've seen an elem and then put it in the result if you've not seen it more than N times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is `vector` a `list`?
2. You should do it in one pass, using an `unordered_map<int,int>` to count occurrences of different values; if it's below the threshold - copy it to a new list, if at the threshold - ignore and move to the next element.

Comment: `vector` is an array, and removing anything from it is costlier than from a `list`.

Comment: 1. Changed the mistake. It was meant to be a vector.

2. I see, I should go read up on this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Scre - this is not a matter of cost; we should use what the requirement says. However, we can argue about the cost of moving `int` elements down in the vector and releasing freed space at the end vs updating `next` pointers in the list.

Comment: @Scre Removing from the back of `std::vector` will be faster than removing from the back of `std::list`. The time complexity is the same but `std::list` will in practice have extra overhead. And depending on the size of the containers and the type of elements, removing from anywhere else may also be faster on `std::vector` than `std::list` in practice even though the time complexity of `std::list` seems better. `std::list` has extra overhead for iterating and destroying elements individually.